# Why cannot the image attachment be transferred properly via google smtp?

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a picture that I have as a string in base64 on e-mail. This is the code I'm using. The message is sent successfully, however I cannot open/preview the picture, neither in browser, nor when I download it.
When I use online image preview-ers that transform base64 to images and pass them  the content of `$qr_base64` variable, they show the picture I need. What could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try
{
    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "pass";
    $mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->addAddress("$mailto", 'John Doe');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
    $mail->msgHTML("asdf");
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    $mail->AddStringAttachment($qr_base64, "Filename.png");
    $mail->send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: It has been a long time since i used `PHPMailer`, but shouldn't there be a `$mail->Body`?  Anyhow, you should capture the email itself.  To be able to preview the image the mail must have `Content-Type: multipart/alternative` and the part that contains the image must have the correct MIME too (e.g. `Content-Type: image/png`).  I suspect you're sending the **base64** with MIME `Content-Type: text/plain`

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: You mentioned `gmail`, it can show you the raw email.  In the top right corner of the message (next to the reply button) are the message options, one of them is `Show original`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div class="class">

    <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Email:<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailfrom" /><br><br>
   Image: <input type="file" placeholder="Image Upload" name="smtpimg" />


                <input type="submit" name="smtp" value="Send SMTP" />


    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>


    <?php
    include "PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php"; 
    if(isset($_POST["smtp"])){
                    $email = $_POST["emailfrom"];
                    $target_dir = "smtpimg/";
    $target_file= $target_dir .time().basename($_FILES['smtpimg']['name']);
    $movefile=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['smtpimg']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "pass";
    $mail->AddReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply name");
    $mail->AddAddress($email,'ashu');
    $mail->Subject = "SMTP Receivced";
    $mail->Body = "<b>Succesfully SMTP Receivced</b>";
    $mail->AddAttachment($target_file);
    $text = 'Text version of email';
    $html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
    $file = 'index.php';
    $crlf = "\n";
    $hdrs = array(
                  'From'    => 'you@yourdomain.com',
                  'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
                  );
    if($mail->send($hdrs))
     {
    echo "<script> alert('Successfully Mailed');window.location = '';</script>";
    }
    else{
    echo "Mailed Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    }
    ?>
```